# How to change directory permissions like made with 'sudo mkdir' in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory

I created the directory with "mkdir" command, after that I need to change permissions as if I made it with "sudo mkdir".

I've searched for the chmod command, but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to do this with a single command in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the chown command to change the owner and group of the directory, and the chmod command to set the permissions.

```
sudo chown root:root /path/to/directory && sudo chmod 755 /path/to/directory
```